# ubuntu installation probs

Tags: dual-boot, wubi

i am trying to install ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS......i booted via usb .....when i start the installation process, i select the language,then tick for "download third party appications" and "check for updates while downloading" and then i get to choose what should i opt for ...so i select "install ubuntu alongside windows 8" and as soon as i click "continue", the computer restarts with windows 8....what should i do? i tried rebooting and also tried to reinstall "wubi" on my pendrive but the same situation occurs....

Comment: Wubi is incompatible with Windows 8 and UEFI and even aside from that it's deprecated since a while.

Comment: The OP isn't installing with Wubi... Clearly states "I booted via USB ... When I start the installation process, I select the language". This is a normal install.

Comment: @Gautam Can you confirm what you see - is it "Install Ubuntu alongside" or "Install Ubuntu *inside*"? Does it reboot immediately  or does it appear to install before rebooting? (1st problem indicates all 4 primary partitions used)

Comment: Check the md5sum of the .iso

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 8.1 then don't choose the option "install Ubuntu alongside with Windows". instead choose ***Something Else*** option and continue the installation.

Comment: actually i did what u said! but the problem is being caused beacause of that option !